# How to reuse/wash brettanomyces yeast

Tags: yeast, reusing-yeast, brettanomyces

I made some apple cider with WLP648 brettanomyces. I'd like to try this yeast in some other experiments. Can I reuse brett like any other yeast? Can I pitch the lees/dregs into a new batch or can I wash the yeast and keep it in a jar in the fridge?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reuse yeast.
I use both homebrew and commercially and everything is ok.
Can carry out normal treatment. Always remembering to sanitize the equipment used, thank you.